# How to do a clustered column and stacked combination chart with Google Charts?

Tags: google-sheets, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to do an stacked and clustered column with google chart in Google Sheets.

Something like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: would this be acceptable? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pveR1.png

Comment: thanks, are they separated charts?

Comment: yes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lww8y0SXkmOsbeT1qIAKNTZ7ggs_6AcsMQW3HaVIIac/edit#gid=1088943141